# How to get buffer into CompletionROUTINE as apart of WSARecvFrom call?

Tags: c, windows, winsock2

I'm working on a UDP server, and am trying to use overlapped IO. I've been trying to use MSDN examples and documentation for research but haven't found use of the `lpCompletionRoutine` argument of the function.

I notice you pass a `PWSAOVERLAPPED` to `WSARecvFrom`, and it contains a `LPVOID Pointer` member. Would I create my own user-data structure that contains a reference to the buffer and pass it as a pointer inside this `Pointer` member of `PWSAOVERLAPPED`?

I thought it was a bit redundant though that the received bytes were available in two places:

`WSARecvFrom`'s `lpNumberOfBytesRecvd` argument, and `lpCompletionRoutine`'s `cbTransferred` parameter.

Example of my current completion routine:

```
void CALLBACK CompletionROUTINE(
  DWORD dwError, 
  DWORD cbTransferred, 
  LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, 
  DWORD dwFlags
) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwError);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpOverlapped);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwFlags);

    /* Best way to get the bytes read here? */
    Printf(L"Recieved %d bytes\n", cbTransferred);
}
```

and my call to `WSARecvFrom`:

```
iResult = WSARecvFrom(
    listenSocket, 
    &wsaBuffer, 
    1, 
    &dwBytesRecieved, 
    &dwFlags, 
    (PSOCKADDR)&sender, 
    &senderAddrSize, 
    &wsaOverlapped,
    CompletionROUTINE
);
```

Comment: Note that the overlapped mechanism is used for other I/O and protocols.  This can result is some overlap, and this is one example.  Better twice than never:)

Comment: I use the hEvent field for transferring a context-object pointer/instance.  That instance includes the buffer/s and the overlapped block.

Comment: @MartinJames How do you go about waiting for the results? You can't seem to use `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` because you're specifying your own event which isn't a valid handle.

Comment: With a WaitForSingleObjectEx loop call on a semaphore, with 'bAlertable set true..  If the WFSO returns with 'WAIT_IO_COMPLETION', I ignore it and any action/s required happen in the completion routine.  If 'WAIT_OBJECT_0' it means that some I/O request object instance is waiting on a queue and it should be dequeued and handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `WSAOVERLAPPED` structure [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741665.aspx):

> hEvent Type: HANDLE
>        If an overlapped I/O operation is issued without an I/O completion routine (the operation's lpCompletionRoutine parameter is
>   set to null), then this parameter should either contain a valid handle
>   to a WSAEVENT object or be null. If the lpCompletionRoutine parameter
>   of the call is non-null then applications are free to use this
>   parameter as necessary.

So since I am providing a `lpCompletionRoutine` parameter, I can use `WSAEvent` as a pointer to my user defined data.

Thank you to the commenter that lead me to this finding.